# Wordpress - Scammy script appears on some pages

Tags: wordpress

I noticed that on a wordpress site I'm going to take over the following scripts are found on multiple pages:

When the page is displayed here is what I see:
[image]

This seems incredibly scammy, does anyone know what this is?

I am going to delete all of those and restrict access to the website in the meantime

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things likely happened. Either you are serving flash and have a really old version on your computer -  OR - your website has been compromised and injected with some sort of malware.

Are the unusual scripts showing up in the content or the theme files? If they are showing up on the content, that means someone has added these scripts to the database, and it will require a bit of cleanup (or a restore to a previous version). If the scripts are showing up in actual .php files, then someone has gained access to the file system on the server.

You should re-install WordPress entirely to ensure all core files are clean, and then go through plugins and themes to ensure all malicious code has been removed.

Also, it would be good to find out how this happened, to attempt to stop it from happening again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far I have only found them in content, not in the theme files. What is strange is that looking in the revision history of each page containing the scripts, I see nothing. The person who did this likely deleted his tracks.